# How do I loop thought each DB field to see if range is correct

Tags: sql, groovy, xquery, soapui

I have this response in soapUI:

```
 <pointsCriteria>
    <calculatorLabel>Have you registered for inContact, signed up for marketing news from FNB/RMB Private Bank, updated your contact details and chosen to receive your statements</calculatorLabel>
    <description>Be registered for inContact, allow us to communicate with you (i.e. update your marketing consent to 'Yes'), receive your statements via email and keep your contact information up to date</description>
    <grades>
       <points>0</points>
       <value>No</value>
    </grades>
    <grades>
       <points>1000</points>
       <value>Yes</value>
    </grades>
    <label>Marketing consent given and Online Contact details updated in last 12 months</label>
    <name>c21_mrktng_cnsnt_cntct_cmb_point</name>
 </pointsCriteria>
```

There are many many many pointsCriteria and I use the below xquery to give me the DB value and Range of what that field is meant to be:

```
<return>
{
for $x in //pointsCriteria
return <DBRange>
<db>{data($x/name/text())}</db> 
<points>{data($x//points/text())}</points>
</DBRange>
}
</return>
```

And i get the below response

```
<return><DBRange><db>c21_mrktng_cnsnt_cntct_cmb_point</db><points>0 1000</points></DBRange>
```

That last bit sits in a property transfer. I need SQL to bring back all rows where that DB field is not in that points range (field can only be 0 or 1000 in this  case), my problem is I dont know how to loop through each DBRange/DBrange in this manner? please help

Comment: Do you have SoapUI-Pro or just the free one?

Comment: Only using the Open source version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again for your help @albciff, I had to add this into a multidimensional array (I renamed `field` to `column` and `result` is a large return from the Xquery above)

```
def resXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(result)
//get the columns and points ranges
def Column = resXml.DBRange.db*.text()
def Points = resXml.DBRange.points*.text()
//sorting it all out into a multidimensional array (index per index)
count = 0
bigList = Column.collect
{
    [it, Points[count++]]
}
//iterating through the array
bigList.each
{//creating two smaller lists and making it readable for sql part later
    def column = it[0]
    def points = it[1]
    //further splitting the points to test each
    pointList = points.split(" ")
    pointList.each
    {//test each points range per column
        def sqlResult = sql.rows "select * from my_table where ${column} <> ",[it]
        log.info sqlResult
    }
}
sql.close();
return;
```

Comment: sorry I doesn't really understand in prof you question, anyways nice to give you an approach `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I really understand your question, however I think that you want to make queries in your DB using specific table with a column name defined in your `<db>` field of your xml, and using as values the values defined in `<points>` field of the same xml.

So you can try using a `groovy TestStep`, first parse your Xml and get back your column name, and your points. To iterate over points if the values are separated with a blank space you can make a `split(" ")` to get a list and then use `each()` to iterate over the points on this list. Then using `groovy.sql.Sql` you can perform the queries in your DB.

Only one more thing, you need to put the `JDBC drivers` for your vendor DB in `$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` and then restart `SOAPUI` in order that it can load the necessary driver classes.

So the follow code approach can achieve your goal:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
// soapui groovy testStep requires that first register your
// db vendor drivers, as example I use oracle drivers...
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
// connection properties db (example for oracle data base)
def db = [
    url : 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_host:d_bport/db_name',
    username : 'yourUser',
    password : '********',
    driver : 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
]
// create the db instance
def sql = Sql.newInstance("${db.url}", "${db.username}", "${db.password}","${db.driver}")

def result = '''<return>
    <DBRange>
        <db>c21_mrktng_cnsnt_cntct_cmb_point</db>
        <points>0 1000</points>
    </DBRange>
   </return>'''

def resXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(result)
// get the field
def field = resXml.DBRange.db.text()
// get the points
def points = resXml.DBRange.points.text()
// points are separated by blank space,
// so split to get an array with the points
def pointList = points.split(" ")
// for each point make your query
pointList.each {
    def sqlResult = sql.rows "select * from your_table where ${field} = ?",[it]
    log.info sqlResult
}

sql.close();
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: ahhh thanks for the update :) I got the SQL part to work without a hiccup (I'm using postgres) and whilst going through this I realised I didn't quite explain myself too well, albeit you are on the same path I'm on.The return portion has multiple values `<DBRange>` in it, I only gave the example of one of (i'm not sure but probably50+) so I think your code was giving me multiple lists of the same stuff -- and now my DB access has died... You've helped a heck of alot thanks albciff - I'm going to play around with this see if i can get it right after some rest –

Comment: ohhh I see, I'm going to have to add this to a multidimensional array so that `bigList = [[c21,0,100],[c22,0,500,1000]` etc, I don't see any other way around this :(